# What is the compatible html/css framework for cakephp?

Tags: html, css, cakephp-3.0

Am looking for the compatible html/css framework that's work perfectly with cakephp,for example in bootstrap most of times you have to modify cakephp files,is there any other frameworks that are easy to use and also compatible with cakephp ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no definitive answer to this as all `html/css frameworks` will require certain classes and id to be used to achieve the styling the framework applies.

There are multiple plugins for using bootstrap with Cakephp but this only tend to adapt how the `flash, forms, html and paginator` display as everything else in cake is generally performed by the developer which mean in your `.ctp` files you tend to sent HTML so it's down to you to use the correct classes and id's.

Comment: i thought that there is a framework close to cakephp classes,forms....,guess i have each time to adapt bootstrap with cakephp

Comment: Use a plugin to handle the main stuff i have used https://github.com/slywalker/cakephp-plugin-boost_cake for Cakephp 2 and https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/bootstrap-ui for Cakephp 3

Comment: Matt,what about handling inputs validation using bootstrap's classes(has-error,has-success...) how to fix that in cakephp ?

Comment: That will all come as part of the plugin mate. The plugin extends the form templates and takes care of classes being added. The `.has-success` one you will need to handle via JS as that will require either frontend processing or ajax submission.

Comment: is there any other way for handling .has-success, .has-error classes inside .ctp file where i created the form?

Comment: There isn't a way `.ctp` files are these are just view files and should only contain presentational logic. You need to check the inputs against some validation rules before you can set `.has-success`. You could maybe loop through inputs with errors in your controller and send an array to the `.ctp` and perform something like an `in_array()` to set a success class. If it is really needed but MVC generally states to not have anything but presentational logic in Views.